# Как вывести промежутки возрастания массива?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        Console.Write("Введите размер массива: "); 
        var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
        int[] a = new int[n]; 
        Console.WriteLine("Элементы массива: "); 
        for (var c = 0; c < n; ++c) 
        { 
            a[c] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
        } 
    }
```

Как сделать вывод промежутков возрастания (на сколько второе число больше предыдущего)?

Comment: Например сохраняя число с предыдущего шага в переменную и анализируя на текущем шаге :)

Comment: Извините, не могли бы вы реализовать это кодом?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++) { Console.Write($"{array[i] - array[i - 1]} ");` }

Comment: Мог бы, но во первых зачем мне это? а главное как это поможет вам научится писать программы?)